# new feature? - all addresses needs to be searchable

Tags: search, search-results, addresses, custom-search, search-builder

In the latest releases of civicrm 4.7.18 onwards ,we can see the supplemental fields are searchable which is a very good feature.

However, one can have multiple addresses and civicrm allows to add multiple addresses to an individual. But, the searching and retrieving is possible only with the primary location for the contact. Searching is not possible for the other addresses. I would like it to happen in future releases.

Comment: Hi there!  Stack Exchange isn't really the best place for a feature request - they should go on https://issues.civicrm.org.  However, it's important to note the saying: "CiviCRM is free to use, but it isn't free to write."  Feature requests are extremely unlikely to be filled unless you can provide resources, either in the form of code, or money to pay for someone to add the feature.

Comment: as it is I didnot make a feature request. I just thrown this up for discussion. Just wanted to know what the civicrm community says about it. As I am new to civicrm, it is possible this feature already available and not known to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the advanced search under the "Address Fields" you can choose "Address Location" which defaults to primary only. By selecting all of them you can search by any address type.  answer taken from this thread [Using custom fields to store secondary addresses](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/using-custom-fields-to-store-secondary-addresses/19043#19043)