# Using custom fields to store secondary addresses

Tags: custom-fields, search, search-results, addresses, search-builder

As of now only primary address of a contact is searchable in advanced search. Search is not possible for other addresses of the same contact. So I want the other addresses of contact also searchable. Can I use custom fields for other addresses apart from primary?

What are the problems that can come up because of this approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the advanced search under the "Address Fields" you can choose "Address Location" which defaults to primary only. By selecting all of them you can search by any address type.

I tested searching for a non-primary "personal" address and the results showed the contact.

It might be something that could be made clearer, because I found a similar thread on it [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=33034.0).